# How to get dojox in Dojo Tool Kit?

Tags: dojo

I can find dojo.js and dijit-all.js but I cannot find the dojox.js. Does anyone know how to build dojox.js? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're asking for a kitchen-sink dojox module, there is none.  The dojox package includes a wide variety of components for various purposes - it wouldn't be a stretch to think of each subfolder of dojox to be its own package, really.  No application would ever use nearly everything in dojox at once - and if it did, its load time would be terrible, because dojox is quite large due to the nature of what it is.

`dijit-all.js` is generally not recommended for a similar reason, though all of dijit is not nearly as large as all of dojox.  Hence the [comment in the module stating as much](https://github.com/dojo/dijit/blob/1.10.3/dijit-all.js#L72).

For that matter, `dojo/dojo.js` is not a kitchen sink per se either.  When used with `async: true`, it is *only* the Dojo loader; without `async: true` (in legacy mode), it is the loader plus `dojo/_base` and its dependencies.

Ideally you should only be loading modules you absolutely need; AMD in particular encourages this as opposed to the legacy `dojo.require` / global namespace system.  If you architect your applications in a reasonable manner with a single top-level module, it is possible to create a custom build with a layer based around that module which will automatically include all its dependencies (and *only* its dependencies).  See the "Layers" section of the [Creating Builds tutorial](http://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/build/).